# Configuring sshd on Windows 10, without having to set "StrictModes no"

Tags: windows-10, sshd

I know next to nothing about Windows systems, and the person I did it for knows very little technical about it, but I managed to enable and configure `sshd` on it.

The public key had to be put into the `C:\Programdata\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` file to allow it to work for a user with admin privileges.

The problem is, it won't work unless I change `sshd_config` to set `StrictModes no`.

That is a bad thing to do, but I know nothing about how permissions work on this file system, much less how to change them.

What needs to be done to avoid this potentially dangerous configuration?

---

I just noticed [linux - Windows 10 sshd - passwordless incoming ssh demands a password - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1415983/windows-10-sshd-passwordless-incoming-ssh-demands-a-password).
One answer suggests doing what I did, and the other suggests removing the `Match Group administrators` configuration.

Both work, but surely defeating these security mechanisms isn't the "correct" solution.

Comment: Can you verify the permissions on the key only allowed the user who intended to use the key?  You have to of course configure the permissions as an Administrator. Did you verify if removing the match group configuration did indeed resolve your problem?  Based on [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1324) GitHub discussion it appears that line only configures a key for Administrators to use anyways. Since the user is not an Administrator, I suggest, disabling the key.  Unless an Administrator requires a key also on the system.

Comment: @Ramhound, the user *is* an administrator (i.e. the only user). ¶ Yes, removing the Match Group avoided the problem. ¶ The mechanism itself is crazy: any ssh to an admin account ignores the user's personal keys file and uses that common keys file for *all* admins. (So for instance, adminuser1 could ssh in as adminuser2, but not as joeuser.) ¶ The "correct" fix should be to correct the file permissions problem, but I have no idea how that works (nor apparently did the responders to the other question).

Comment: If this server is accessible from outside of your intranet then you should think twice about commenting it out.  However, the simplest solution to that problem, is disallow administrators from accessing the machine through SSH. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication) Stack Overflow question has the commands to fix the permissions on the key

Comment: Is this system perhaps configured to a locale where the Administrator group is something other than Administrator? By removing the group key configuration, you are preventing a single key from being used, but it also doesn't exist so it can't be used.  The reason remoting the configuration works is because, that is the key that is attempted to be used first, and I suspect OpenSSH isn't attempting to use the user's key.  Without logs I can't diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, security isn't really an issue in this specific case. I just like to understand how to do things the "right" way. Finding two different ways of defeating a security mechanism in order to allow the thing it was designed to protect to work, just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Removing the shared Administrator key configuration is a valid solution.  Without more details I will be unable to answer your question.  You should address that by performing an [edit] to your question.

Comment: @Ramhound, if this were Unix-like system, something like "chmod go-rwx" would fix the problem.

Comment: There is a similar set of commands on Windows which has been provided.